# How to find all colliders below mouse?

Tags: unity-game-engine, raycasting

```
 public static bool IsTopmost(GameObject go)
 {
     RaycastHit[] hits;
     Vector3 wp = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
     wp.z = Camera.main.transform.position.z;
     hits = Physics.RaycastAll(wp, Vector3.forward, Vector3.Distance(Camera.main.transform.position, go.transform.position) * 2);

     if (hits.Length == 0)
     {
         return false;
     }

     GameObject topMostSoFar = hits[0].collider.gameObject;

     RaycastHit hit;
     for (int i = 1; i < hits.Length; i++)
     {
         hit = hits[i];

         if (Compare(topMostSoFar, hit.collider.gameObject) == -1)
         {
             topMostSoFar = hit.collider.gameObject;
         }
     }

     Debug.Log("finishes method");
     return topMostSoFar.name == go.name;
 }
```

My camera position.z = -5, all sprites in the game position.z = 0. This method never finishes, it always enters the first if which says there are no colliders under the mouse position. What do I do wrong here?

**EDIT: It turns out my mistake is very stupid, I'm using Physics instead of Physics2D for 2d colliders. How can I check same thing but with 2d raycasting?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use the 2d methods and variable types everywhere and for the direction of the RaycastAll to use Vector2.zero, unless you put Vector2.zero it;s not going to work.